# Key handling with KeyPreview in TForm.OnKeyDown does not work with TListBox

Tags: delphi, onkeydown, delphi-10.1-berlin, keypreview

A. Create a VCL Forms Application.

B. Put a TListBox on the form and fill in some items at design-time, for example:

[image]

C. Set the Form's `KeyPreview` property to `True`:

[image]

D. In the Form's `OnKeyDown`event-handler write this code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = VK_BACK then
  begin
    if ListBox1.Focused then
    begin
      Key := 0;
      CodeSite.Send('ListBox1 is focused!');
    end;
  end;
end;
```

E. Run the program and select Item5 by clicking on it:

[image]

Now ListBox1 has the focus.

F. Now press the BACKSPACE key. Supposedly, setting `Key := 0;` in the Form's `OnKeyDown`event-handler should block the BACKSPACE key from being processed by the ListBox1 control. But this does not work, as you can see: The BACKSPACE key caused to change the selection from Item5 to Item1:

[image]

So how can I prevent the BACKSPACE key from being processed in the focused ListBox control and to change the ListBox's selection?

Delphi 10.1 Berlin Update 2
Windows 7 x64 SP1

Comment: Read about WM_GETDLGCODE

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: And what value would you propose returning from that message? There is no flag that says to ignore backspace keystrokes. Are you thinking of disabling the `DLGC_WANTALLKEYS` and/or `DLGC_WANTCHARS` flags, or enabling the `DLGC_WANTMESSAGE` flag?  You are going to have to be more specific.

Comment: TranslateMessage is called before DispatchMessage in the message loop, therefore you haven't prevented a WM_CHAR (which is translated from the WM_KEYDOWN) to be posted to the list box. Hence Remy's answer....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `OnKeyPress` event instead:

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if Key = #8 then
  begin
    if ListBox1.Focused then
    begin
      Key := #0;
      CodeSite.Send('ListBox1 is focused!');
    end;
  end;
end;
```

You can't always block everything in `OnKeyDown`.

Comment: Thank you, it works. But this is amazing, as `OnKeyDown` occurs **BEFORE** `OnKeyPress`, and ALTHOUGH `Key` ist explicitly set to zero in `OnKeyDown` the event `OnKeyPress` is still called! I was always convinced that keys like `BACKSPACE` don't trigger `OnKeyPress`.

Comment: Normally `OnKeyPress` is not called if `OnKeyDown` rejects a key. Notice my answer said to use `OnKeyPress` **instead of** `OnKeyDown`, not with it.  In any case, `Key` in `OnKeyDown/Up` is a *virtual key code*, but `Key` in `OnKeyPress` is a *translated character*, so they are not always the same value (in this case, they are).

Comment: Strangely, blocking the `HOME` key and the `END` key with `Key := 0;` in `OnKeyDown` DOES work and no `OnKeyPress` event is being triggered with these keys. Why? Why this different handling of these keys?

Comment: `Home` and `End` are not **characters** and dont trigger `OnKeyPress` at all (try it). `Backspace` is a **character** (Unicode codepoint `U+0008`). `OnKeyDown/Up` are triggered in reply to `WM_KEYDOWN/UP` messages that carry virtual key codes from the keyboard, even for non-character keys, but `OnKeyPress` in triggered in reply to `WM_CHAR` which only carries characters: "*[`WM_CHAR`] Posted to the window with the keyboard focus when a `WM_KEYDOWN` message is **translated** by the `TranslateMessage()` function. The `WM_CHAR` message contains the **character code** of the key that was pressed*"

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, it is much appreciated!